# npm run serve errors with completing task manager. Won't complete and run on local browser

Tags: npm

I am having difficulty with npm run serve for a tutorial I'm doing through Udacity. For some reason, the npm task manager keeps breaking when trying to run the BABEL and Browserify tasks and will not complete serving on any port. Would love to get this resolved.

[image]

Comment: Could you please give more information about what are you exactly doing?

Comment: Please take a tour of [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). have a look at [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) Also on how to [Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sure thanks. I started an assignment that uses a git repo `git@github.com:jakearchibald/wittr.git` . Pretty simple . Clone repo. cd in. npm install. Then npm run dev. For some reason the npm task manager keeps breaking when it comes to loading the BABEL and Browserify tasks. I've tried all the troubleshootings tips from the repo as well as recloned and reinstalled npm. Super frustrating. Wondering if I have a node package installed globally that is interfering somehow ?

Comment: Figured out it was hidden babel.json and .babelrc files located in the root npm dependencies that prevented the npm run serve from completing all the tasks.